# AS3 SocketServer and mobile client

Tags: sockets, actionscript

I have written an ActionScript 3 class that is a Server Socket and accepts connections.

I want to write a client in order to send data to the server.

The client will be a mobile browser. I think that i will use javascript.

Does anyone know any reference to study. Is it possible to connect to the server from mobile enviroment??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to connect to a socket server with javascript running in a mobile browser. If this is correct, here are some links to get you started:

[The Official WebSocket Documentation](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/)

A javascript library that will make development easier: [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/)